# 3-regular planar Graphs with 5 and 6 sided faces

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have the following question: For what number $n$ does there exist a 2-connected planar graph $G$ with $n$ vertices such that $G$ is 3-regular and every face of $G$ has degree either 5 or 6?

My progress so far:
Let $a$ be the number of faces with degree 5, $b$ be the number of faces with degree 6, and $m$ be the number of edges. Then
\begin{align*}
&3n=2m&& a+b-m+n=2 && 2m=5a+6b.
\end{align*}
[...solving linear equation system...] Hence $a=12$, $n=20+2b$, and $m=30+3b$ and there could be a graph for any even $n\geq20$.

There exists such a graph with $b=0$ (the Ikosaeder), one for $b=2$, and one for $b=20$ (a football).
However, I am quite certain that there is no such graph for $b=1$. The problem I see is that the equations above do not capture the 3-regularity of the graph.

Do you see any way to impose further restrictions on $n$ or a proof for which $n$ a graph exists?

Comment: Why is $2m=5a+6b$ true? Are you assuming each edge is part of two different faces? Maybe it's trivial, but I don't see it

Comment: You are right, in a planar graph every edge is adjacent to two faces. Alternatively, in a planar 3-regular graph every vertex is adjacent to 3 faces. Hence $3n=5a+6b$.

Comment: Why can't the edge be only part of the outer face? for example if the planar graph is a tree? A tree could not be 3 regular, but it is planar, so I think the statement "every edge is adjacent to two faces in a planar graph" is wrong. Same thing for vertices.

Comment: Oh sorry you are right, I assumed the graph to be 2-connected.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker Suppose $G$ has an edge $e$ which is only part of the outer face, which must be a bridge. Since $G$ is $3$-regular, there are at least $3$ vertices on the outer face on each side of the bridge. Each of these sets of $3$ vertices contributes at least $3$ to the degree of the outer face, and $e$ contributes $2$, so the degree of the outer face is at least $8$, contradiction.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Thanks! You basically proved every $3$-regular planar graph is $2$-connected, right?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker no, only ones with maximum face degree at most $7$ (it's not true otherwise).

Comment: Of course, it is still true that if you add all the face degrees you get twice the number of edges, because if a face is only on the outer face then it contributes $2$ to its degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that there is no such graph with $b=1$. I don't know of an easy way to show this, however. In fact such graphs exist for every other value of $b$, and the number of such graphs for each value of $b$ is given by [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A007894).